# Finding an angle without calculator

Tags: geometry

Given a triangle $ABC$. Let D be a point on side BC such that $BD=2$, $DC=6$. If $AB=4$ and $\angle ACB=20^{\circ}$, find $\angle BAD$.

With the help of calculators this problem can be easily solved by the Law of Sines, however this is a contest problem where calculators aren't allowed. Without help of calculators, is it possible to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: check the similarity of $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta ABD$

Answer:

> Triangles with One Equal Angle and Two Sides Proportional are Similar. Reference: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Triangles_with_One_Equal_Angle_and_Two_Sides_Proportional_are_Similar

Answer (score 2):

Since $BA^2 = BD\cdot BC$ a line $BA$ touches the circle through $A,D,C$.

Thus $\angle BAD = \angle DCA = 20^{\circ}$.

Comment: @MathEnthusiast: You should better wait to get other solutions, before you accept an answer.